# Package.swift manifest not found ("has no Package.swift manifest for ...")

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

Using the default flow to create new Swift Package, I created one and put it in a bitbucket repo. The files inside have the following structure:
[image: Package structure]

The problem is that, when i try to add it to a project, i get an error that Package.swift is not found.
[image]

It seems, that the Package.swift file is not found, if it is not on the root level level of the repo. But if i move the Package.swift file on the same level as "TestSwiftPackage" root folder, the package dependencies all get broken.
I tried to add specific paths for target and testTarget, but it still wont work.
[image: Pakcage.swift file content]

How should the Package.swift look like to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue with the Package setup.
Just have to find the correct paths to both targets.
Here is the working setup.
[image]

Comment: Had this same issue.  For those that visit this page, my issue was not providing the correct path to the dependency.  Must have typed the path, left, came back and forgot to finish the path.  This should actually be sent to Apple as a bug because the  error should state "Dependency not found at path" instead of thinking the whole manifest is missing.